# Expanding animation on click

Tags: javascript, css, animation, elementor, expand

I'm facing a problem right know about css & javascript animations, let me explain, I have two columns with a box of information and a button to "see more" on each one. What I want to do is to expand 1 column when I click the button, taking the fullwidth of the viewport and making the other column to hide under the column that expands, then, when the columns is opened, I want to display a closing button to shrink the column and being able to see both columns again, but I think I can take over the closing button.

I will attach an image where you can visualize my problem.

By the way, I'm working with Wordpress and elementor, but I asume I will need code to do this, it's a great opportunity to learn!

Thanks to everybody and have a nice day!

[image]

> Blockquote

```js
let buttonInsolite = document.querySelector(".button-insolite");

let buttonAttribute = document.querySelector(".button-attribute")

let containerInsolite = document.querySelector(".container-insolite-1");

let containerAttribute = document.querySelector(".container-attribute-1");

let sectionInsolite = document.querySelector(".section-insolite-2");

let sectionAttribute = document.querySelector(".section-attribute-2");

let closeInsolite = document.querySelector(".close-insolite");

let closeAttribute = document.querySelector(".close-attribute");

buttonInsolite.addEventListener("click", function() {
    containerAttribute.style.display = "none";
    sectionInsolite.style.display = "block";
    closeInsolite.style.display = "block";
    closeInsolite.addEventListener("click", function() {
        containerAttribute.style.display = "block";
        sectionInsolite.style.display = "none";
        closeInsolite.style.display = "none";
    })
})

buttonAttribute.addEventListener("click", function() {
    containerInsolite.style.display = "none";
    sectionAttribute.style.display = "block";
    closeAttribute.style.display = "block";
    closeAttribute.addEventListener("click", function() {
        containerInsolite.style.display = "block";
        sectionAttribute.style.display = "none";
        closeAttribute.style.display = "none";
    })
})
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container-insolite-1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background: #9C030333;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.container-insolite-2 {
    display: flex;
}

.section-insolite-1 {
    padding: 0px 50px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.section-insolite-2 {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.close-insolite {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.container-attribute-1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background: #E6E6E6;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.container-attribute-2 {
    display: flex;
}

.section-attribute-1 {
    padding: 0px 50px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.section-attribute-2 {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.close-attribute {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-insolite-1">
        <button class="close-insolite">X</button>
        <div class="section-insolite-1">
            <h3>INSOLITE</h3>
            <p>Empresa de IT</p>
            <p>Somos una empresa de IT que trabaja para ayudar a progresar a los negocios haciendo humana la tecnología.</p>
            <br>
            <button class="button-insolite">Servicios de INSOLITE</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section-insolite-2">
            <p><strong>Servicios de INSOLITE</strong></p>
            <div class="container-insolite-2">
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Development</strong></p>
                    <p>Webpages</p>
                    <p>App</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Cloud</strong></p>
                    <p>Infrastructures</p>
                    <p>Digital Wordspace</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Business Value</strong></p>
                    <p>Analytics & Business Intelligence</p>
                    <p>Product & Service Creation (alongside ATTRIBUTE)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-attribute-1">
        <button class="close-attribute">X</button>
        <div class="section-attribute-2">
            <p><strong>Servicios de ATTRIBUTE</strong></p>
            <div class="container-attribute-2">
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Brand Building</strong></p>
                    <p>Brand Strategy</p>
                    <p>Verbal Identity</p>
                    <p>Visual Identity</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Experience</strong></p>
                    <p>Customer Experience</p>
                    <p>Business Design</p>
                    <p>Service Design</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Activation</strong></p>
                    <p>Product & Service Creation</p>
                    <p>Go-to-market</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-attribute-1">
            <h3>ATTRIBUTE</h3>
            <p>Business Transformation Consultants</p>
            <p>Somos una consultora de transformación de negocio que entiende la marca como el eje estratégico de nuestro trabajo.</p>
            <br>
            <button class="button-attribute">Servicios de ATTRIBUTE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what have you already done to try and achieve this?

Comment: Well, I've wrote a code using query selectors to do an action when you click it, and I've tried multiple css combinations using the animation property, it works, but I don't achieve the animation that I want, and also it doesn't take over the other column, it only shrinks, sorry if my English sucks!

Comment: It's common on SO to make something yourself first and then share that code. We can then help you on the part you are stuck with. Also a tip for sharing that code, use the code snippet (<> icon in editor). We can then run the code snippet to see the result of the script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello again Kip. I just updated my question and attached the code snippet, my problem now is that I don't know how to apply a transition or animation to make it look smoother. Also I'm struggling with a bug... when I first expand a column it displays correctly, but when I close it and expand another column, it is displayed incorrectly, with the info stacked over the other, without applying the "display: flex;" property on "container-insolite-1" & "container-attribute-1". I don't know if I'm explaining myself

Comment: By the way @Kip feel free to tell me if my code sucks or I should change my way of coding, I really want lo learn and improve

Comment: Nevermind @Kip ! I find the solution to the bug I mentioned earlier, there's only the animation/transition issue left :D

Comment: For animation/transition I usually use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick example for you. I have replaced `.display = "none";` with `.fadeOut(500);` and `.display = "block";` with `.fadeIn(500);`

You could also try and do some stuff with `.animate()`:

```
.animate({
    width: "toggle" // or use 500px / vw / % what every you like and need.
});
```

❤️ https://jquery.com/

```js
let buttonInsolite = document.querySelector(".button-insolite");

let buttonAttribute = document.querySelector(".button-attribute")

let containerInsolite = document.querySelector(".container-insolite-1");

let containerAttribute = document.querySelector(".container-attribute-1");

let sectionInsolite = document.querySelector(".section-insolite-2");

let sectionAttribute = document.querySelector(".section-attribute-2");

let closeInsolite = document.querySelector(".close-insolite");

let closeAttribute = document.querySelector(".close-attribute");

buttonInsolite.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //containerAttribute.style.display = "none";
    $(".container-attribute-1").fadeOut(500);
    //sectionInsolite.style.display = "block";
    $(".section-insolite-2").fadeIn(500);
    closeInsolite.style.display = "block";
    closeInsolite.addEventListener("click", function() {
        //containerAttribute.style.display = "block";
        $(".container-attribute-1").fadeIn(500);
        //sectionInsolite.style.display = "none";
        $(".section-insolite-2").fadeOut(500);
        closeInsolite.style.display = "none";
    })
})

buttonAttribute.addEventListener("click", function() {
    containerInsolite.style.display = "none";
    sectionAttribute.style.display = "block";
    closeAttribute.style.display = "block";
    closeAttribute.addEventListener("click", function() {
        containerInsolite.style.display = "block";
        sectionAttribute.style.display = "none";
        closeAttribute.style.display = "none";
    })
})
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container-insolite-1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background: #9C030333;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.container-insolite-2 {
    display: flex;
}

.section-insolite-1 {
    padding: 0px 50px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.section-insolite-2 {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.close-insolite {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.container-attribute-1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background: #E6E6E6;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.container-attribute-2 {
    display: flex;
}

.section-attribute-1 {
    padding: 0px 50px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.section-attribute-2 {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.close-attribute {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-insolite-1">
        <button class="close-insolite">X</button>
        <div class="section-insolite-1">
            <h3>INSOLITE</h3>
            <p>Empresa de IT</p>
            <p>Somos una empresa de IT que trabaja para ayudar a progresar a los negocios haciendo humana la tecnología.</p>
            <br>
            <button class="button-insolite">Servicios de INSOLITE</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section-insolite-2">
            <p><strong>Servicios de INSOLITE</strong></p>
            <div class="container-insolite-2">
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Development</strong></p>
                    <p>Webpages</p>
                    <p>App</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Cloud</strong></p>
                    <p>Infrastructures</p>
                    <p>Digital Wordspace</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Business Value</strong></p>
                    <p>Analytics & Business Intelligence</p>
                    <p>Product & Service Creation (alongside ATTRIBUTE)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-attribute-1">
        <button class="close-attribute">X</button>
        <div class="section-attribute-2">
            <p><strong>Servicios de ATTRIBUTE</strong></p>
            <div class="container-attribute-2">
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Brand Building</strong></p>
                    <p>Brand Strategy</p>
                    <p>Verbal Identity</p>
                    <p>Visual Identity</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Experience</strong></p>
                    <p>Customer Experience</p>
                    <p>Business Design</p>
                    <p>Service Design</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p><strong>Activation</strong></p>
                    <p>Product & Service Creation</p>
                    <p>Go-to-market</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-attribute-1">
            <h3>ATTRIBUTE</h3>
            <p>Business Transformation Consultants</p>
            <p>Somos una consultora de transformación de negocio que entiende la marca como el eje estratégico de nuestro trabajo.</p>
            <br>
            <button class="button-attribute">Servicios de ATTRIBUTE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try to work with .animate like you said, because fadeOut and fadeIn don't give the effect I'm looking for, though, thanks for all the help, I didn't know about the JQuery library, I can see it's very useful and I'm going to start using it!